# WCF Post operation runs into 400 bad request - invalid host name on local host IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I could use some help, as I've been stuck for 2 days now. I have googled, but not been able to find the right solution.

Can anyone help on how to fix, or how to debug better?

What is being sent to the localhost

```
POST /Service1.svc/addt HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost.:13309
Content-Length: 25 
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The response (viewed with fiddler)

```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The GET operation is working fine, so I feel it's really the POST operation is wrong.

For information below the Web.config and the Post operation

```
string requestData = "{\"ID\":1,\"Make\":\"Ferrari\"}";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost.:13309/Service1.svc/addt");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse webr = request.GetResponse();




<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FinanceService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="FinanceService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I've changed the formatting of the HTTP request to what it most likely looked like. Your line breaks just didn't make sense.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dot after `localhost`? I've never seen an valid address with a dot between the host name and the colon before the port number.

Comment: The . after localhost is added so fiddler will pick it up. The results stays the same if I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself - by starting with the files from a tutorial, getting those to work, and then step-by-step making changes, till I have my required result.

Praise to this [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201901/CREATE-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Using-POST-Step-By)

Looking at the large number of items on 400 bad request in combination with WCF Post, here some pointers.

1. Web.Config does not seem to need much attention. If it works for GET, It most likely is properly configured for POST actions
2. The format of the body/data you want to post is very fidgety! If you claim it is JSON, make sure it is proper JSON. My (naive) impression was that whatever I put into the body, would come out on the other end, but apperently the server does a check, and returns "bad request".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to debug better. I'd strongly recommend to don't add . after `localhost`. Most likely you are getting another error in that case.

Please refer to '[Why don't I see traffic sent to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic)'

> The simplest workaround is to use your machine name as the hostname instead of Localhost or 127.0.0.1. So, for instance, rather than hitting http://**localhost**:8081/mytestpage.aspx, instead visit http://**machinename**:8081/mytestpage.aspx.

Hope that helps you to catch real error which is related to usage POST method.

Comment: Link dead, try this: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NInject to activate it, you should use NinjectServiceHostFactory.